# excel dimensionalizing values for an array post compile vba

Tags: excel, vba

i want to be able to initialize an array to store the values of a conversion. but i don't know how many values there will be until compile time so i want the range to go from

pseudo-code:

```
1 to <some expression>
```

namely i want it as

```
Dim Colvals(1 To Len(EndColumn)) As Integer
```

but when the code is sent to compile it throws

```
Constant Expression required
```

any idea how to do it? i really don't want to limit the versatility of the program by forcing the specification of the range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to redimension your array using a Redim statement:

```
Dim Colvals() As Integer
ReDim Colvals(1 To Len(EndColumn))
```

It seems strange that it requires a Constant for the Dim and not the Redim, but it's true.

Comment: +1: ReDim would be the way! As a note to OP, you should use LONG instead of INTEGER. Excel and VBA will work with Long by default, plus you don't want to run into a situation where you have gone over the bounds of Int.

Comment: I second Issun's statement about using Long.